# Random position func

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have 2 objects (dvere1, dvere2) having their positions. How to set up random func that these two objects by pressing changed their position. I am a beginner

Here is my code:

```
    var dvere1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "D")
var dvere2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "D")



override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()


    dvere1.position = CGPoint(x:self.view!.bounds.width / 1.5, y:self.view!.bounds.height/1.9)
    addChild(dvere1)
    dvere2.position = CGPoint(x:self.view!.bounds.width / 3.1, y:self.view!.bounds.height/1.9)
    addChild(dvere2)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `arc4random_uniform` method as follow:

```
var randomPostion = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view!.bounds.width))), y:CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view!.bounds.height))))

dvere1.position = randomPosition
```

Comment: announced a error : Cannot invoke 'arc4random_uniform' with an argument list of type '(CGFloat)'